# Multitasking with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an Android app which should work both online and offline and I'm using Glide for image loading. After downloading the database I want to start two tasks in parallel: download all images to disk and load all images required on current screen (and then next screens). The problem is that amount of images to download is very large and the ones requested for current screen seem to be added at the end of the same download queue. So I end up with "empty" screens untill all the images are downloaded to disk cache. How can I make these tasks work in parallel?

```
public class GlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_glide);
        downloadAllImages();
        updateUi();
    }

    private void updateUi() {
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view2);
        ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view3);
        cachedGlideRandomRequest().into(imageView1);
        cachedGlideRandomRequest().into(imageView2);
        cachedGlideRandomRequest().into(imageView3);
    }

    private void downloadAllImages() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            cachedGlideRandomRequest().preload();
        }
    }

    private DrawableRequestBuilder<String> cachedGlideRandomRequest() {
        return Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=" + System.nanoTime() % 1000)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE);
    }
}
```

What I want is to show images on ImageViews while `downloadAllImages()` is still working on background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that Glide does have an elegant solution for my case. That's the `priority()` method. It allows setting LOW priority for "download all" and IMMEDIATE for "on screen" image. Here's some [reading about this API](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-request-priorities). And the code I've ended with:

```
private void downloadAll(List<String> imageUrls) {
    for (String image : imageUrls) {
        Glide.with(this).load(image).priority(Priority.LOW).preload();
    }
}

private void downloadOnScreen(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
    Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE).into(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a placeholder image to display immediately:

```
cachedGlideRandomRequest()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.resource_to_show_now)
    .into(imageView1);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm searching for, but nice workaround.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to make two download queues or two instances of Glide. Then I'll be able to "download all" in Service while still downloading required images for Activities.

Comment: And calling updateUI before downloadAllImages isn't working, if the queuing works the way you suspect?

Comment: It works for this Activity, but after moving to the next one download queue seems to be loaded for a very long time ahead. And images appear on UI only after "download all" finishes.

Comment: Yeah, Glide isn't really going to manage arbitrarily large amounts of downloads for you.  The problem it's trying to solve is getting an image into an ImageView on demand, then canceling that when not needed any more.  If you want to manage a cache of content with specific behavior, your best bet is to do that yourself, and have Glide work with your own managed cache.

Comment: Sadly enough, you were wrong. I've just found a way to solve this problem by setting request priorities. Take a look at my answer for details.

Comment: Bear in mind that the priorities as described do not implement separate queues, as you asked, nor do they give an ordering guarantee.  Specifically I would guess that if you have stalled, low priority requests currently being processed and occupying the max number of download threads, that could be prevent higher priority images from being processed.  I'd still definitely put the high prio requests in the queue first before the others.

Comment: Right, that's not a perfect solution, but still it solves the problem just great.